# Instagram-style navigation bar hiding

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I need to hide the navigation bar when the user scrolls down. Currently, I'm calling `setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES` on scroll, but this solution isn't ideal as it makes the main view jump up as soon as the animation is called.

The Instagram app has a much better solution - the navigation bar is locked to the top of the main view, and it scrolls up as the user scrolls. Scroll down a few pixels, and only part of the nav bar gets hidden.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar. 
Its very easy to use, just subclass `AMScrollingNavbar` in your viewController

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are using a navigation bar. I think it's custom header view for the UITableView, or at least that's what I would do since you can put any UIView there.

You can use the UITableView delegate to set those headers.

Comment: If it was a header view, wouldn't the scroll bar cover it up when it appears? In Instagram, when the scroll bar appears, it appears below their navigation bar - suggesting that it is an actual navigation bar. Unless there's a way to make the scroll bar appear only for certain subviews?

Comment: @bmueller it definitely is not a table header, because refresh control appears under it =) i found the way they did it - read my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273289/instagram-like-navigation-bar-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

navigation bar doesn't provide this function. the best way is to use a custom view (your custom navigation bar) as a subview of the main view, then do the animations yourself, using functions like [UIView animateWithDuration ....] with translation function using something like CATransform3DTranslate

Comment: Same question as for @Jorsh - if I was to use a custom view, wouldn't the scroll bar appear over top of the custom view? Is there a way to make the scroll bar appear only in certain subviews?

Answer (score 0):

I have found exactly the way Instagram did it - check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273289/instagram-like-navigation-bar-ios-7)
No pan gesture recognizers, setting bars hidden, nothing like that, just some cool engineering inside `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of the table view